# A multiple choice question in complex analysis, related to maximum and minimum of $|f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ denote the closed unit disk and let $\partial D$ denote its boundary. Then which of the following hold for every analytic function $D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

a) $|f|$ attains  its  minimum and its  maximum on $\partial D$

b) $|f|$ attains  its  minimum  on $\partial D$ but need  not attains its  maximum on $\partial D$

c) $|f|$ attains  its  maximum  on $\partial D$ but need  not attains its  minimum on $\partial D$

d) $ |f|$ need  not attains  its maximum on $\partial D$ and also it need not attains its  minimum on $\partial D$

**My efforts**

I know it is a very simple question so please bear with me.

**Approach 1:Using theorem**

> Maximum modulus principle: Suppose $f$ is analytic in $D$ and
>   continuous on $\partial D$. Then the maximum of $|f(z)$ which is
>   always reached, occurs somewhere on the boundary of $D$ and never in
>   the interior.

So by this theorem $a,b,d$ are false. So $c$ is the correct choice.

**Approach 2: Using examples and counterexamples**

I also want to try this approach as example provide me a great source of learning.

I take $f(z)=z$, identity function. $|f|$ attains its maximum on the boundary with maximum value $1$ and minimum value on the center of disk with minimum value zero.

So $a$ is false, $b$ is false, $d$ is also false.

---

**Extra questions:**

What can we say about the minimum value of the $|f|$. Under what condition it is always attained and where?

Comment: Concerning your extra question: The so-called *minimum principle* may be helpful in this situation - it says that if $f$ is holomorphic and non-vanishing on the bounded domain $G$ (i.e. $f(z) \not = 0$ for all $z \in G$) and continuous on the boundary of $G$, then $|f|$ will also attain its minimum on the boundary $\partial G$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've solved everything except the extra questions. You've also already observed that $f(z)=z$ has its minimum modulus on the interior. This is basically the only exception. Since $|f(z)|\geqslant 0$, the minimum of $|f|$ will occur at the zeros of $f$ if there are any. Thus the minimum modulus can (and will) be in the interior if $f$ is zero somewhere in the interior.

If $f$ is not zero anywhere in the disk $D$, $1/f$ is holomorphic. In this case, the maximum modulus theorem applied to $1/f$ tells you that the minimum modulus of $f$ must occur on the boundary.